# Stripping $ from php values

Tags: php

I have a form where users can enter the amount they spend on their phone bill and then I tell them how much they could save if they switched to vonage, skype etc.

I pass the value "$monthlybill" in the url and then do some math to it.  The problem is that if the user writes "$5" instead of "5" in the form, it breaks and is not recognized as a number.  How do i strip out the dollar sign from a value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$monthlybill = str_replace("$", "", $monthlybill);
```

You might also want to look at the [money_format function.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) if you are working with cash amounts.

Comment: Thank you.  As always people here saved my ass!

Comment: Whenever you run into something that you think may require regex to solve, look for things like str_replace, substr_replace, substr, strrchr, etc... they can work wonders and are often easier than trying to craft a funky regex.

Answer (score 3):

[Ólafur's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580019/stripping-from-php-values/580029#580029) solution works, and is probably what I'd use, but you could also do:

```
$monthlybill = ltrim($monthlybill, '$');
```

That would remove a $ at the beginning of the string.

You can then validate further that it is a monetary amount depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function extract_decimal($str)
{
    $match = preg_match('/-?\d(\.\d+)?/', $str, $matches);
    return $match ? $matches[0] : null;
}
```

This function will trim away anything that isn't part of the number (including dollar signs) and also supports negative numbers and decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is user input, you'll probably want to strip all non-numeric characters from the variable.

```
$BillAmount = preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', $BillAmount);
```